# How to implement cascading form with async requests?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a form like this:

```
<input text />
<select dropdown1 />

<select dropdown2 />
<select dropdown3 />
```

flow is:

1. input text is always shown
2. dropdown1 is always shown
3. dropdown2 and dropdown3 are shown only if particular options in dropdown1 is selected
4. dropdown3 values are gotten from http request based on dropdown2 value (its actually done through redux, connect and actions dispatching but point is, its async)

i am not sure how to organize flow for this scenario and set initial values for all cases.
i dont need any particular code but advice about when to set what especially focusing on initual values.

for example, how to set initial value for dropdown2 and dropdown3?

is this a good usecase for `getDerivedStateFromProps` which would set state (inputs are controlled) based on props passed (from `connect`)?
or should i use only `componentDidUpdate` and set values based on props changed (including redux ones)?

Comment: have you tried something already, can you show?